# Fast array chunking in Node.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, chunks, array-splice

I'm working with array chunking at long datasets. I need to create a new array of chunks of a certain size. Currently, I use this solution but it shows bad performance.

```
function array_to_chunks(data, size){
   let chunks = []
   let d = data.slice()
   while (d.length >= size) chunks.push(d.splice(0, size))
   return chunks
}
```

I'd like to find some better idea of how to do it fast enough and why my code does not perform well.

Comment: Are you using I/O with this? If so, use Node.js streams. Otherwise, you are buffering everything.

Comment: No, I don't. Actually, this is impossible due to the project current state.

Comment: Definitely use a, or sub-class of, `WritableStream`.

Comment: I added another idea. Interested to hear your opinion on it in terms of performance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is slightly more performant because you don't have to copy the array:

```
const createGroupedArray = function (arr, chunkSize) {

    if (!Number.isInteger(chunkSize)) {
        throw 'Chunk size must be an integer.';
    }

    if (chunkSize < 1) {
        throw 'Chunk size must be greater than 0.';
    }

    const groups = [];
    let i = 0;
    while (i < arr.length) {
        groups.push(arr.slice(i, i += chunkSize));
    }
    return groups;
};
```

if you are doing I/O, then use Node.js streams:

```
const strm = new Writable({
  write(chunk, enc, cb){
     // do whatever
  }
});
```

Comment: `slightly more performant` - by my calculation it is up to 400x faster! depending on original array size and chunk size of course (make that over 700x faster)

Comment: Unfortunately, I have to copy it, as 'data' is being accessed by other methods of object (provided code is an adaptation)

Comment: I think you misunderstand ... you have to copy it in your code because `.splice` mutates the original ... `.slice` does not alter the original array, therefore, you don't **need** to copy it, as the original array remains untouched

Comment: what sizes are you talking about ... as in, length of original array, and length of  chunks (note, I think your original code would not return everything if the array length is not an exact multiple of chunk size

Comment: @JaromandaX,  each element of array is ~434 bytes. and array length is ~500,000 entries

Comment: I don't care about element size ... I care about array size and chunk size

Comment: @JaromandaX, Ok now I get it! I'll try to rewrite code and respond

Comment: Works better, but not as much. Thanks anyway for your help

Comment: @FelixRiverwood `slice` should be fine. This approach is the same as the answer I deleted. I'm afraid you can't do better than this in terms of big-O runtime.

Comment: MrCholo reigns supreme! lulz

Comment: @JaromandaX Element size would matter depending on the data type... Unless there are no true primitives in js. Would not deleting the original at the very least mean you now have to store an extra array of references? IE it might be faster coputation at but use more memory for sufficiently large array. But if it were an array of u8 then moving all the u8 values would be cheaper than copying an array of pointers to the originals.

Comment: @ThisGuyCantEven - I can't remember what I had for breakfast, let alone a reason for a comment from 5 years ago :p

Answer (score 0):

you can use lodash [chunk](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#chunk) method, this does what  you need

```
const _ = require('lodash');
_.chunk([1,2,3,4,5,6],2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am interested to hear your opinion on this approach:

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
const size = 5

const chunkIt = (arr, size) => {
  let buckets = []

  // Just create the buckets/chunks storage
  for (let i = 1; i <= Math.ceil(arr.length / size); i++) {
    buckets.push([])
  }

  // Put in the buckets/storage by index access only
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var arrIndex = Math.ceil((i + 1) / size) - 1
    buckets[arrIndex].push(arr[i])
  }

  return buckets;
}

console.log(chunkIt(arr, size))
```

I did some basic JS benchmarking and it did do well. The idea is to pre-create the buckets since that operation should not be that expensive and then just push by index.